# ¿Como hacer un LIMIT en Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Necesito mostrar una cierta cantidad de valores en una vista.

Quiero hacer algo como `SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT 4`

Pero la necesito hacer en Laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El método take() del Query Builder es el que cumple esta función:

```
$resultado = DB::table('tabla')->take(4)->get();
```

Como siempre puedes ver más info en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

También puedes ver lo que hace este método en el código del framework: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1464